# DomContainer.Eval to open popup does not return

Tags: watin

I am calling a script to open up an alertbox using Eval function like below:

```
ie.DomContainer.Eval("alert('just a test')");
```

However this does not return and it hangs there.
Any other javascript call in Eval works fine as long as it does not produce a popup.
Does anyone know how to close the alertbox or modal dialog that results from eval?

I am using IE9, Watin 2.1.0.1196.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Watin 2.0 / IE8, the popup closes automatically.  Can you try the very basic test as listed below?

My NUnit test is as follows.

```
    [Test]
    public void EValTest()
    {
        IE myIE = new IE(true);
        myIE.GoTo("www.google.com");
        myIE.DomContainer.Eval("alert('just a test')");
    }
```

Comment: I tried the simple test you suggested and what I found is that using IE8/XP did dismiss the alert box automatically, but on IE9/Win7, the alert box does not go away.

Comment: I don't currently have an IE9 testbox, so my hands are tied.  When I get one I'll give this a look, but hopefully someone else can figure this out in the meantime.